# Set Multiple <select> options from HTML Attribute (Get .attr as Array) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

What I have is an  that opens up a Jquery popup with a form in it. This form has a  with multiple options (you can select more than one at a time). I am trying to use a "countries" attribute of the  to select multiple selections (see example below).

This WORKS:

```
<a href="#" id="openpop"> //The link

....
//The Popup HTML
<select id="countryselection" multiple="multiple">
<option>US</option>
<option>CA</option>
<option>GB</option>
</select>

....
//The event handler
$("#openpop").click(function(){
loadPopup();
("#countryselection").val(['US', 'CA']);
});
```

So the example above works fine...

This ALSO WORKS:

```
<a href="#" id="openpop" countries="US"> //The link with countries attribute

....
//The Popup HTML
<select id="countryselection" multiple="multiple">
<option>US</option>
<option>CA</option>
<option>GB</option>
</select>

....
//The event handler
$("#openpop").click(function(){
loadPopup();
("#countryselection").val([$(this).attr("countries"), 'CA']); //Notice the this.attr
});
```

The problem is, I need to set MULTIPLE countries, all from the countries attribute of the  tag.

It doesn't work when I try it...

This DOES NOT WORK:

```
<a href="#" id="openpop" countries="'US','CA'"> //The link with multiple countries

....
//The Popup HTML
<select id="countryselection" multiple="multiple">
<option>US</option>
<option>CA</option>
<option>GB</option>
</select>

....
//The event handler
$("#openpop").click(function(){
loadPopup();
("#countryselection").val([$(this).attr("countries")]); //Notice the this.attr
});
```

I hope you can see what I am trying to do here. Somehow I need the Jquery to take in the "countries" attribute as an array, although I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/V62Yq/

```
<a href="#" id="openpop" countries="US,CA">link</a>

<select id="countryselection" multiple="multiple">
    <option>US</option>
    <option>CA</option>
    <option>GB</option>
</select>
​

//The event handler
$("#openpop").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var vals = $(this).attr('countries').split(",");
    $("#countryselection").val(vals); 
});​
```

And though adding a country attribute is kind of valid depending on the html spec you are targeting, you should likely use data attributes for information such as "countries" in your link tag. You can access them the same way.

```
$(selector).attr('data-countries');

<a href="#" id="openpop" data-countries="US,CA">link</a>
```

See: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: +1: Congratulations on your first SO answer, Chris. Well written, and a working jsfiddle. Nice! I made some tiny changes to your answer. The link to John Resigs blog wasn't working, and the data-countries stuff wasn't formatted as code. BTW: There are no downvotes on your answer as of right now.

Comment: Hi Christoffer and thanks! When I tried to add the link to the HTML5 Data-Attributes, the site said I wasn't privileged to post more than 2 links, even though there was only one other.

Thanks for the edits and the feedback! I've been a long-time lurker and just figured I could help out SO by contributing back :)

Comment: Thanks - the split function worked great. What does e.preventDefault(); do?

Comment: prevents the default dom action of the element that was clicked. In this case, an <a> tag. We don't really want the browser to follow the href/empty hash. It is a method added to the event that is passed into the function .click(function(e) { by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

suppose we have this attribute: `data-countries="US, CA"` in `<a href="#" id="openpop" data-countries="US, CA"> ... </a>`

we can make an array from this, this way:

```
con = $("a").data('countries');
arr = con.split(",");
alert(arr[0])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jV7Cn/

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you're trying to use an attribute to store structured data, however, if you're allowed to define you countries attribute as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="openpop" countries="US,CA">
```

You could use the Javascript [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to turn it into an array.  For example:

```
("#countryselection").val($(this).attr("countries").split(/,/));
```

The problem with your original line:

```
("#countryselection").val([$(this).attr("countries")]);
```

...is that Javascript is taking the actual string value of the attribute, `$(this).attr("countries")` and using it as the lone element of the anonymous array, being passed to `val()`.  Although the value of this attribute looks like array syntax, you should be aware that it is not parsed as such.  Only Javascript source you enter into your text editor (or string arguments to `eval()`) are interpreted.